# Is there any way to "scrobble" to libre.fm using Banshee?

Tags: banshee

Well , is there any way to "scrobble" to libre.fm using Banshee? (i'm on banshee 2.1)

I found out that rhythmbox can do it, but i prefer banshee.

Comment: Having the same issue and much prefer Banshee (currently 2.6.2) over constantly buggy Rhythmbox (3.02), but the Libre.fm feature keeps me tied to it. Is there any development since 2011 about Libre.fm the authentication system? Can't see anything in the bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [bug filed on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=579801) for just this sort of request.  Reading through the bug-report, it appears the developers are complaining about the authentication system libre.fm uses.

Doesnt appear to be any resolution to this yet.

Comment: I'll probably move to rhythmbox for now then. Thanks